# Google Admob does not work Unfortunately Phonegap error

Tags: eclipse, cordova, admob

It's been two days I'm trying to solve my problem with Admob can anyone help me?

Below is my code.

Meu Logcat

```
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021): Exceção fatal: main
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021): java.lang.RuntimeException: Não E Possível instanciar Atividade ComponentInfo {com.phonegap.helloworld / com.phonegap.helloworld}:. Java.lang ClassNotFoundException: com. PhoneGap. olamundo
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma android.app.ActivityThread performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java: 1879)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma android.app.ActivityThread handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java: 1980)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma android.app.ActivityThread Acesso $ 600 (ActivityThread.java: 122)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  um android.app.ActivityThread $ H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java: 1146)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma android.os.Handler DispatchMessage (Handler.java: 99)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  um android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java: 137)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma android.app.ActivityThread principal (ActivityThread.java: 4340)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma java.lang.reflect.Method invokeNative (Método Nativo)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma java.lang.reflect.Method invocar (Method.java: 511)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma com.android.internal.os ZygoteInit $ MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java: 784)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma com.android.internal.os ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java: 551)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  um dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Método Nativo)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021): Causada Por:. Java.lang ClassNotFoundException: com.phonegap.helloworld
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma dalvik.system BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java: 61)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma java.lang.ClassLoader loadClass (ClassLoader.java: 501)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma java.lang.ClassLoader loadClass (ClassLoader.java: 461)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  um android.app.Instrumentation. newActivity (Instrumentation.java: 1023)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  . uma android.app.ActivityThread performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java: 1870)
04-10 16:16:08.131: E / AndroidRuntime (2021):  ... 11 Mais
```

Meu manifesto

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8">
<! -
   Licenciado de para um Apache Software Foundation (ASF) EM UM
   UO Mais Contratos de Licença de Colaborador. Veja o ARQUIVO de AVISO
   distribuido com Este Trabalho parágrafo obter Informações Adicionais
   los Relação à Propriedade de Direitos autorais. Uma ASF licencia Este ARQUIVO
   A Voce soluçar uma LICENÇA Apache, Versão 2.0 (a
   "Licença"); Você. Localidade: Não PODE USAR ESSE ARQUIVO EXCETO los Conformidade
   com uma LICENÇA. Você. PODE obter UMA Cópia da LICENÇA los

     http://www.apache.org/ licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   A Menos Que exigido POR lei APLICÁVEL OU POR Escrito Acordado,
   software distribuido soluçar uma LICENÇA E distribuido
   "COMO ESTA", SEM Garantias OU CONDIÇÔES DE QUALQUÉR
   Tipo, Expressa UO implícita. Consulte a LICENÇA parágrafo o
   permissões Específicas AO Seu idioma e limitações
   soluçar uma LICENÇA.
->
<Xmlns manifestas: android android = " http://schemas.android.com/ apk / res / android ": windowSoftInputMode =" adjustPan "
  Pacote = "com.phonegap.helloworld" android: versionName = "1.0" android: versionCode = "1" android: hardwareAccelerated = "true">
<Telas Suporta
    android: largeScreens = "true"
    Android: normalScreens = "true"
    Android: smallScreens = "true"
    Android: xlargeScreens = "true"
    android: resizeable = "true"
    android: anyDensity = "true"
    />

<Usa-permissão android: name = ". Android permission.INTERNET "/>

<Aplicativo Android: icon = "@ drawable / Ícone" android: label = "@ string / app_name"
    android: hardwareAccelerated = "true">
    <Atividade Android: name = "HelloWorld" android: label = "@ string / app_name"
            android: theme = "@ android: Estilo / Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android: configChanges = "Orientação | keyboardHidden | Teclado | screensize | locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <Ação android: name = ". Android.intent action.MAIN "/>
            <Categoria android: name = ". Android.intent category.LAUNCHER "/>
        </ Intenção-filter>
    </ Atividade>

    <Atividade android: name = "com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges=" keyboard|keyboardHidden| orientation|screenLayout| uiMode|screenSize| smallestScreenSize"/>
</ Application>
<Usa-permissão android: name = ". Android permission.INTERNET "/>
<Usa-permissão android: name = ". Android permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_ ESTADO "/>
<Usa-permissão android: name = ". Android permission.READ_PHONE_STATE "/>
<Usa-sdk android: minSdkVersion = "10" android: targetSdkVersion = "19" / >
</ Manifesto>
```

Meu arquivo main.xml

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8">
<Xmlns LinearLayout: android = " http://schemas.android.com/ apk / res / android "
          xmlns: anuncios = " http://schemas.android.com/ apk / lib / com.google.ads "
          android: Orientação = "vertical"
          android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
          android: layout_height = "fill_parent">

<Com.google.ads.AdView android: id = "@ + id / ADView"
                     android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
                     android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
                     Anuncios: adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-9756726447441686 / 6270780460 "
                     Anuncios: adSize = "bandeira"
                     Anuncios: testDevices = "TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     Anuncios: loadAdOnCreate = "true" />
</ LinearLayout>
```

I am using Admob GoogleAdmobSDK 6.4,1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it has anything to do with Admob.

The error you are getting is

```
Java.lang ClassNotFoundException: com.phonegap.helloworld
```

You have basic classpath issues with your project.